# JQuery, use selectors on page that is loaded into a variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, greasemonkey

I'm writing a greasemonkey script with some JQuery in it.

I load a number of pages into variables. I use the $.get to get the pages in the variables/array. That works fine.

Now I'am wondering how I can extract data from pages that are stores in the variables by using jquery selectors.

What I want to do is write stuff like this:

```
mypages[i].(".foo a").each(function( index ) {...});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/eq perhaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you *really* want to do is write stuff like this:
`$(mypages[i]).find(".foo a").each(...)`

the jQuery object is very non-discriminatory. It will accept just about anything and convert it into a jQuery-like object, so assuming that `mypages[i]` is either an HTML string, jQuery object, or DOM Element, that should do it for ya